# bind doesn't seem to be working on all items

Tags: sparql, rdf, semantic-web, owl, ontology

This is the minimum data

```
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
PREFIX rs: <http://www.SemanticRecommender.com/rs#>
PREFIX mo: <http://www.musicontology.com/mo#>
PREFIX  : <http://www.musicsemanticontology.com/mso#>

mo:5th_symphony_for_beethoven a mo:GermanSymphony .
mo:nabucco_overture a mo:OperaOverture .
rs:operaWeek2016 a rs:TemporalContext ; rs:appliedOnItems  mo:OperaOverture .
rs:SymphonyFestival2016 a rs:TemporalContext ; rs:appliedOnItems mo:GermanSymphony .
```

This is the query

```
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
PREFIX rs: <http://www.SemanticRecommender.com/rs#>
PREFIX mo: <http://www.musicontology.com/mo#>
PREFIX  : <http://www.musicsemanticontology.com/mso#>

SELECT distinct ?item ?temporalContextWeight ?temporalContext ?itemClassTemporal 
    WHERE
      {
  {
    values (?item) {(mo:new_world_symphony)(mo:nabucco_overture)(mo:5th_symphony_for_beethoven )}
  }
  OPTIONAL
          { 

            ?temporalContext
                      rdf:type           rs:TemporalContext ;
                      rs:appliedOnItems  ?itemClassTemporal .
            ?item     rdf:type           ?itemClassTemporal
     values ?temporalWeight {100000}
          }
        VALUES ?defaultNoTemporalContext2 { 1 }

        BIND(if(bound(?temporalWeight), ?temporalWeight, ?defaultNoTemporalContext2) AS ?temporalContextWeight)
      }
```

This is the result

[image]

as you see, there is one row for each **item**, however, there should be two rows, because i have **two** instances of `rs:TemporalContext` class, and even if the `item` is not from the class `?itemClassTemporal`, there is an bind to bind the default value

**This is just a replication of the problem, the real query and real data is complex**

#### Update

After the first answer i can see the reason why the binding is not working, however, i updated my question as bellow and still the binding **or something else** not working

```
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
PREFIX rs: <http://www.SemanticRecommender.com/rs#>
PREFIX mo: <http://www.musicontology.com/mo#>
PREFIX  : <http://www.musicsemanticontology.com/mso#>

SELECT distinct ?item ?temporalContextWeight ?temporalContext ?itemClassTemporal 
    WHERE
      {
  {
    values (?item) {(mo:new_world_symphony)(mo:nabucco_overture)(mo:5th_symphony_for_beethoven )}
  }
  OPTIONAL
          { 

            ?temporalContext
                      rdf:type           rs:TemporalContext ;
                      rs:appliedOnItems  ?itemClassTemporal .
    optional{#new
            ?item     rdf:type           ?itemClassTemporal
     values ?temporalWeight2 {100000}
    }#new
    bind(if (bound(?temporalWeight2), ?temporalWeight2, 1) as ?temporalWeight)
          }
        VALUES ?defaultNoTemporalContext2 { 1 }

        BIND(if(bound(?temporalWeight), ?temporalWeight, ?defaultNoTemporalContext2) AS ?temporalContextWeight)
      }
```

look now there is another optiona of the trible that ?item is from ?itemClassTemporal

Comment: If you just return the OPTIONAL part as a separate SELECT query, does the resultset changed after your update?

Comment: @AKSW no no change

Comment: That's what I expected. But then of course the whole query doesn't lead to a different result. I don't know what you expect from the inner OPTIONAL that wraps `?item  rdf:type  ?itemClassTemporal`. Can you clarify this?

Answer (score 1):

`mo:new_world_symphony` => no OPTIONAL match => one row.

Simplifying:

```
SELECT *
WHERE
  {  ?temporalContext
              rs:appliedOnItems  ?itemClassTemporal .
    ?item     rdf:type           ?itemClassTemporal
  }
```

has one match each ?item.

For a specific `?temporalContext` there is one `rdf:type rs:TemporalContext`.

Comment: okay but not that what i want, i want a row for each TemporalContext, could you help please ?

Comment: I have updated my question adding the new query after understindg your answer, but the new query still gives one row for each context, though i have added another optional ,could you check pleaes? i really apppreciate it

Comment: Start with a simpler query that gets part fo what you want then add to it.